# References for $\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i k(x-a)}$

Tags: reference-request

In a website, [Integral and Series Representations of the Dirac Delta](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17#iii), I found this series expansion of the Dirac delta function
$$\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i k(x-a)}$$
For this formula the website refers to unspecified "physics literature". I'd like to find a bibliographic reference for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, maybe you should look for something like: "completeness relation for plane waves"

Comment: Why cite a reference?  This is fairly straightforward to show.

Comment: @Dr.MV, not for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**

The Complex Fourier Series on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ for a function $f$ is written

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{inx} \tag 1$$

where the coefficients $c_n$ are given by

$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx \tag 2$$

Substituting $2$ into $(1)$ reveals that

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x')e^{-inx'}\,dx'\right)\,e^{inx}$$

whereupon formal interchange of the series and integral yields

$$f(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x')\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\,e^{in(x-x')}\right)\,dx' \tag 3$$

Inasmuch as $(3)$ is true for all "test functions" $f$, then we deduce that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\delta(x-x')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\,e^{in(x-x')}}$$

---

**METHOD 2:**

Assume that $f$ is a sufficiently smooth "test function" on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  We examine the functional $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}e^{in(x-a)}\right)\,dx$ in the sense of distributions.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}e^{in(x-a)}\right)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=n}^{N}e^{in(x-a)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{in(x-a)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)(x-a)\right)}{\sin((x-a)/2)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin\left((N+1/2)(x-a)\right)\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{\sin((x-a)/2)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&+\frac{f(a)}{2\pi}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)(x-a)\right)}{\sin((x-a)/2)}\right)\,dx \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, if we assume that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{\sin((x-a)/2)}$ is absolutely integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then by  the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Statement), the limit, as $N\to \infty$, of the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ goes to zero.

The second integral is equal to $2\pi$ for all integer $N$.  Therefore, for every suitable test function $f$, we have

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}e^{in(x-a)}\right)\,dx=f(a)$$

Again, we deduce that for $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}e^{in(x-a)}}$$

as expected!